# Extjs not loading data from store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm learning extJS and trying to create simple application following [this](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/application_architecture) and [that](http://likeadev.com/show/simple-ext-js-4-application-tutorial-part-1.html) guides.

My **app.js** file:

```
sstore = new Ext.data.Store({
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'educationId', 'townId'],
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        url: "data",
        reader: {
            type:"json",
            root: "users"
        }
    }
});


Ext.application({
    name: 'Application',
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    controllers: ['MainController']
});
```

**Viewport.js**:

```
Ext.define('Application.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    layout: { type: "vbox", align: 'stretch' },

    items :  [{
        xtype: 'mainList',
        autoScroll: true
    }]
});
```

**List.js**:

```
Ext.define('Application.view.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.mainList',
    title : 'Users',

    store: sstore,     // ***** LOOK HERE PLEASE *****
    //store: 'Users',

    columns: [
        { header: 'Имя',  dataIndex: 'firstName' },
        { header: 'Фамилия', dataIndex: 'lastName' },
        { header: 'Образование', dataIndex: 'educationId'},
        { header: 'Город', dataIndex: 'townId'}
    ]
});
```

Store (**Users.js**) :

```
Ext.define('Application.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',    
    storeId: 'usersStore',    
    //model: 'Application.model.User',    
    fields: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'educationId', 'townId'],    
    autoLoad: true,    
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'data',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
        }
    },    
    onProxyLoad: function (aOperation) {
        console.log('From store');
        console.log(aOperation);
    }

});
```

When I'm changing `store: sstore` on `store: 'Users'` in my List.js file, it's not loading any data, but with store created in app.js file, which lives in sstore variable, it works ok.

What I tried and it didn't help:

- using memory proxy,
- used `store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('usersStore'),`
- it's not problem with backend data (because `sstore` works fine)

I can see that the store from **Users.js** is loading (because the console output from `onProxyLoad` function).

This is what I see in a browser:

[image]

Full js app lives [here](https://github.com/jehaby/Cognitive/tree/master/public)

My view file is [here](https://github.com/jehaby/Cognitive/blob/master/resources/views/index.php)

And I'm using extJS 4.2

Answer (score 0):

This was really stupid. Problem was in [onProxyLoad](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-onProxyLoad) function. When I deleted it from store app worked as I expected.

Comment: Ye, it's generally best not to override private members but it's useful to know that if you do you can include the line `this.callParent(arguments);` or `this.callOverridden(arguments);` on older version of the framework - inside the function to ensure that the default behaviour is retained.